# Error using TensorFlow with input strings in dynamic_rnn and LSTMCell

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use TensorFlow to solve a supervised problem. It is simple:

- A list of strings inputs. The string has a format: "words_10-06-2017"
- A list of floats outputs. The label is a float: 3.0

I want to use a string set with that format and a set of float labels to train a model.

#### System information

- Windows 7 x64
- Tensorflow 1.2
- Python 3.5.2
- IDE Pycharm 2017.1.1

I am using this piece of code:

```
# Input placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None, 1, 1])

...

# Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.first_label_neurons, forget_bias=1)
# Get lstm cell output
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.string)
dropout = tf.nn.dropout(outputs[-1], keep_probably)
# Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
y_prediction = tf.matmul(dropout, weights) + biases
```

The problem is in this line:

```
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.string)
```

This is the output:

***ValueError: An initializer for variable rnn/lstm_cell/kernel of  is required***

Could this be a TensorFlow problem?

Thanks for your attention

The all output:

```
File "D:\ComputerScience\workspaces\model.py", line 602, in rnn_lstm
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.string)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 574, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 737, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2770, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2599, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2549, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 722, in _time_step
    (output, new_state) = call_cell()
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 708, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 542, in call
    lstm_matrix = _linear([inputs, m_prev], 4 * self._num_units, bias=True)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1017, in _linear
    initializer=kernel_initializer)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1065, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 962, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 360, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 183, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 352, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 690, in _get_single_variable
    name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 770, in _get_default_initializer
    % (name, dtype.base_dtype))
ValueError: An initializer for variable rnn/lstm_cell/kernel of <dtype: 'string'> is required
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a word to vector embedding for your inputs. Basically tensor flow can deal with only int and float inputs as of now. So make a vector representation of your input word sequences

Comment: Yes. I fix it with Skip-Gram. 

A nice RNN-LSTM tutorial with TensorFlow?

Thanks!